# Set the value of an input tag with type="password" using C# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have this input tag:

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" runat="server" />
```

I'm trying to set its value using C# and ASP.Net before the page loads, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't set the input type in your markup or ASP.NET will clear the input before it is rendered. Instead, use the following markup:

```
<input id="tbPassword" name="password" runat="server" />
```

...and the following code in your code-behind:

```
tbPassword.Value = "your password";
tbPassword.Attributes["type"] = "password";
```

However, I strongly advise against this approach. For one, you shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text. It's a really bad security practice.

Two, if you're just going to set the password in code, why require it at all? The point of a password input is for user interaction (entering a password). If you do that for them, then having it on the page is pointless.

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave the type as Password but set the value through attributes, e.g. `tbPassword.Attributes["value"] = "secret";`

Comment: Setting `Attributes["value"]` does not work, though Kevin's solution does. (And the remarks on security work too, +1)

Comment: @Jeff, it worked fine for me (when I found myself doing this sort of thing), but that was in .NET 2.0 -- and maybe it depends on when you do it.  Either way, it's a hack.

Comment: @harpo - you can do something similar, but you have to subclass the TextBox and override its pre-render behavior, (As described in ["ASP.NET Password TextBox"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNET_Password_TextBox.aspx) ).

Comment: What a pain, but works great.  I wish Microsoft would have given us a property to turn off this default behavior instead.  In my case I just want the password field to stay field in if the user submits the form with invalid info.  Since it's all going over SSL, doesn't seem like a real security issue for this usage.  I guess if a user does "view source" they'll see it in plain-text, but browser shouldn't be caching these pages anwyay.  I see lots of sites that work this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value of `<asp:TextBox>` using `TextBox.Attributes.Add`, then set the `value` property for the textbox.

code sample:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("value", "My Sample Password");
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 0):

This is by design for security reasons. What are you trying to fill the textbox with? You're not storing user's passwords in plain text are you?

Comment: It's not a real website, it's a school project where they don't care about many security things (like passwords being saved in plain text).

Comment: I think there is no harm in following the best practices even for the basic projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a user login form, and you have access to the unencrypted password, you're doing it WRONG.

User passwords should be stored as a cryptographic hash in your database, which cannot be reversed into the plaintext password, only checked for a match.

If what you want to do is preload the user's password in the input box to save him some typing, just don't do it, because the user's web browser will probably do a better job at that.

Comment: Look on the comment I wrote to bkaid's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   password.value= "something";
}
```